# No persistence using MagicalRecord (iOS6)

Tags: iphone, ios, persistence, magicalrecord

Developing an application for iPhone, we stumbled upon a problem with persisting a text attribute. We are using the follow structure:

Datacore Model:
Report has multiple Items
Item has attributes 'text' and 'position'
Item is a superclass for TextItem and TitleItem
They both have more specific attributes (those attributes are saved correctly)

Models:
We have an Item super for TextItem and TitleItem, and they are generated from the DataCore Model.

ViewControllers:
ItemViewController is a super to TitleItemViewController & TextItemViewController

Views:
TitleItemView & TextItemView are subclasses to ItemView

We are using the following code to save our textItem (in the ViewWillDisappear method in TextItemViewController):

```
[MagicalRecord saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
TextItem *ti = [self.textItem MR_inContext:localContext];
    NSString *newText = [self getText];
    ti.text = newText;
} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Could not save");
    }
}];
```

This doesn't save. We get the message that the there are no changes, although we logged the objects, and the text attribute DOES change. The weird thing is that the text is saved somewhere (even if the message says it's not). We can use the app and it keeps the correct text. Only when we rerun the application, the text has reset to default values (we create the textItem with some default text, but when it loads, it reads the text out of the loaded Model).

We think the problem might be in the inheritence, because other values are saved correctly, but the text attribute is an attribute that is used for all of our Item type objects.

Comment: Have you tried saveWithBlock (i.e. not the saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlock) method? Has always worked for me.

Comment: Nope, doesn't do the trick, still no changes detected. The saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlock method works fine in other situations, so I don't think that this method is the problem

Comment: Is self.textItem not nil?